# How to select rows with 2 specific criteria where one criteria depends on what is the value of another

Tags: r

Hi I have a dataframe that looks something like this (The actual dataframe has many more rows and many more columns but these are the columns I am specifically looking at right now):

```
     Male_ID   Mate_ID  Year  Pair_Number
  1        A         B  1987            1
  2        A         C  1987            2
  3        E         D  1988            2
  4        E         F  1990            1
```

I'm trying to select the row that contains the ID of the first mate that the male mated with. I want to choose the rows with the lowest year value and the lowest Pair_Number within that given year so I'm trying to make sure I choose the first row and the 3rd row.

I've tried this code:

```
        d <- ddply(dataframe, .(Male_ID), summarise, Year = min(Year), Pair_Number = min(Pair_Number))
        results <- left_join(d, dataframe, by = c("Male_ID", "Year", "Pair_Number))
```

But the first code gives me back this:

```
          Male_ID   Year   Pair_Number
       1        A   1987            1
       2        E   1988            1
```

Row 1 is correct but the second row is not. In the year 1988, Male E did not have a Pair_Number equal to 1.

I wanted this:

```
          Male_ID   Year  Pair_Number
       1        A   1987            1
       2        E   1988            2
```

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand it right, don't you want row 4 also? The year is different.

Comment: No because I want to find the first mate ever of the male. Row 4 does not give us the first mate that male E mated with, it gives the second mate he mated with in his lifetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Male_ID, Year) %>% 
  filter(Pair_Number == min(Pair_Number)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  distinct(Male_ID, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  Male_ID Mate_ID  Year Pair_Number
   <fctr>  <fctr> <int>       <int>
1       A       B  1987           1
2       E       D  1988           2
```

1. Group by `Male_ID` and `Year`
2. Filter these groups by minimum `Pair_Number`
3. Ungroup
4. Return first row of each distinct `Male_ID`

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me. The Male_ID column is removed when I do this. The code doesn't take into account the Year or Pair_Number column either, so I'm not sure if this is going to work for me

Comment: Ah. `Male_ID` should not be missing, `Mate_ID` is though because that's what your desired `df` looks like. I forgot about the `Year` and minimum `Pair_Number`. Will update the answer.

Comment: @JenniferDiamond I think it should work for you now.

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R` only.
First the dataset.

```
dataframe <- read.table(text = "
  Male_ID   Mate_ID  Year  Pair_Number
  1        A         B  1987            1
  2        A         C  1987            2
  3        E         D  1988            2
  4        E         F  1990            1
", header = TRUE)
```

Now the code.

```
sp <- split(dataframe, dataframe$Male_ID)
result <- lapply(sp, function(x) x[which.min(x$Year), ])
result <- do.call(rbind, result)
row.names(result) <- NULL
rm(sp)    # tidy up
result
#  Male_ID Mate_ID Year Pair_Number
#1       A       B 1987           1
#2       E       D 1988           2
```

Note that I have created the variable (of class `list`) `sp` just to make the code more readable. Maybe you can skip that part and do

```
result <- lapply(split(dataframe, dataframe$Male_ID), function(x)
    x[which.min(x$Year), ])
```

followed by the rest of the code. But I find it that readable code is better code.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` and keeping all the variables in the final result (which you can remove if needed):

```r
df <- read.table(text = "Male_ID   Mate_ID  Year  Pair_Number
1        A         B  1987            1
2        A         C  1987            2
3        E         D  1988            2
4        E         F  1990            1", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Male_ID) %>%
  arrange(Year, Pair_Number, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  slice(1)

#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Groups:   Male_ID [2]
#>   Male_ID Mate_ID  Year Pair_Number
#>     <chr>   <chr> <int>       <int>
#> 1       A       B  1987           1
#> 2       E       D  1988           2
```